# How to collapse a tibble by combining rows into a list?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

As part of a `dplyr`/`tidyr` wrangling pipe, I arrived at a *tibble* that looks like that:

```r
trb <-
  tibble::tribble(~person,   ~data_name,       ~data_obj,    ~some_string,
                  "chris",   "df_mtcars",      mtcars,       "abc",
                  "rachel",  "df_trees",       trees,        "efg",
                  "john",    "df_iris",        iris,         "hij",
                  "nicole",  "df_plantgrowth", PlantGrowth,  "klm",
                  "ron",     "df_women",       women,        "nop", # | notice that both ron's rows have same values
                  "ron",     "df_cars",        cars,         "nop", # | except for data_name and data_obj
                  "jillian", "df_sleep",       sleep,        "tuv")
```

This table describes 6 people and the data object each person prefers. Annoyingly, `"ron"` gave 2 data preferences, so I need to somehow collapse ron's info into one row of `trb`.

My "collapsing strategy" is to combine both ron's data preferences inside a named list such that the final output will be

```r
trb_output <-
  tribble(~person,   ~.dat,                     ~some_string,
          "chris",   mtcars,                    "abc",
          "rachel",  trees,                     "efg",
          "john",    iris,                      "hij",
          "nicole",  PlantGrowth,               "klm",
          "ron",     list("df_women" = women,
                          "df_cars"  = cars),   "nop",
          "jillian", sleep,                     "tuv")
```

One critical note is that I must get this done *on the pipe*. That is:

```r
# demo to desired solution
trb_output  <- 
  trb %>%
  wrangle_this(...) %>%
  wrangle_that(...)

trb_output  
## # A tibble: 6 x 3
##   person  .dat             some_string
##   <chr>   <list>           <chr>      
## 1 chris   <df [32 x 11]>   abc        
## 2 rachel  <df [31 x 3]>    efg        
## 3 john    <df [150 x 5]>   hij        
## 4 nicole  <df [30 x 2]>    klm        
## 5 ron     <named list [2]> nop        
## 6 jillian <df [20 x 3]>    tuv
```

Is this possible to do using just piping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it with `purrr`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

trb %>%
  group_split(person) %>%
  map_dfr(function(df) {
    if (nrow(df) > 1) {
      tibble(person = unique(df$person), .dat = list(map(df$data_obj, ~.x) %>% set_names(df$data_name)), some_string = unique(df$some_string))
    } else {
      transmute(df, person, ".dat" := data_obj, some_string)
    }
  })
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   person  .dat             some_string
#>   <chr>   <list>           <chr>      
#> 1 chris   <df [32 × 11]>   abc        
#> 2 jillian <df [20 × 3]>    tuv        
#> 3 john    <df [150 × 5]>   hij        
#> 4 nicole  <df [30 × 2]>    klm        
#> 5 rachel  <df [31 × 3]>    efg        
#> 6 ron     <named list [2]> nop
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Edit: More general approach using `across` instead of manually calling `unique` in each column.

```r
trb %>%
  group_split(person) %>%
  map_dfr(function(df) {
    if (nrow(df) > 1) {
      other_cols <- summarise(df, across(-c(data_obj, data_name), ~ unique(.)))
      bind_cols(other_cols, tibble(.dat = list(map(df$data_obj, ~.x) %>% set_names(df$data_name))))
    } else {
      select(df, -c(data_obj, data_name, some_string), ".dat" := data_obj, some_string)
    }
  })
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   person  .dat             some_string
#>   <chr>   <list>           <chr>      
#> 1 chris   <df [32 × 11]>   abc        
#> 2 jillian <df [20 × 3]>    tuv        
#> 3 john    <df [150 × 5]>   hij        
#> 4 nicole  <df [30 × 2]>    klm        
#> 5 rachel  <df [31 × 3]>    efg        
#> 6 ron     <named list [2]> nop
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

data:

```
trb <-
    tibble::tribble(~person,   ~data_name,       ~data_obj,    ~some_string,
                    "chris",   "df_mtcars",      mtcars,       "abc",
                    "rachel",  "df_trees",       trees,        "efg",
                    "john",    "df_iris",        iris,         "hij",
                    "nicole",  "df_plantgrowth", PlantGrowth,  "klm",
                    "ron",     "df_women",       women,        "nop", # | notice that both ron's rows have same values
                    "ron",     "df_cars",        cars,         "nop", # | except for data_name and data_obj
                    "jillian", "df_sleep",       sleep,        "tuv")
```

Comment: This is a very cool approach. But unlike `trb`, in my real data I have many more columns (> 15), so calling `unique()` for every column is going to be tedious. Is there a way to generalize the `unique()` calls and apply `unique()` over *all* cols (except for `data_name` & `data_obj`)?

Comment: @Emman We can use `across(-c(data_obj, data_name), ~ unique(.))` in that case. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. This is the chosen answer because it groups by `person` only, which makes it substantially faster than the other answers in case the data contains many columns of various kinds.

Answer (score 4):

Do either of these work for you?

```
trb2 = trb %>%
  nest_by(
    person, some_string
  ) 


trb3 <- trb %>%
  group_by(
    person, some_string
  ) %>%
  summarise(
    dta = list(data_name = data_obj)
  )
```

Edit, this one?

```
trb4 <- trb %>%
  group_by(
    person, some_string
  ) %>%
  summarise(
    dta = ifelse(length(data_obj) > 1, list(as.list(setNames(data_obj,data_name ))), data_obj))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. `trb3` gets closer, but still falls short of the expected output because we need to simplify one level of nesting in `dta` such that the elements in `dta` list-column will be just the data frames, and in the case of `ron` be a list of 2 dataframes.

Comment: New option given

Answer (score 3):

This may not be perfect, but this seems to work:

```r
trb %>% 
  group_by(across(c(-data_obj, -data_name))) %>% 
  summarise(data_obj = ifelse(length(data_obj) > 1, lst(setNames(data_obj,data_name)), data_obj))

  person  some_string data_obj        
  <chr>   <chr>       <list>          
1 chris   abc         <df [32 x 11]>  
2 jillian tuv         <df [20 x 3]>   
3 john    hij         <df [150 x 5]>  
4 nicole  klm         <df [30 x 2]>   
5 rachel  efg         <df [31 x 3]>   
6 ron     nop         <named list [2]>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost there! However, the list for `ron` isn't exactly as I hope: I need it to have names for the list elements inside, i.e., `df_cars` and `df_women`. Do you have an idea how to name those elements as in `list("df_women" = women, "df_cars"  = cars)`?

Comment: You can use `tibble::lst`

Comment: Right but if you unpack the named list in row 6 of your output (`ungroup() %>% slice(6) %>% pull()`), you'll see it's not identical to `list("df_women" = women, "df_cars"  = cars)` in terms of nesting hierarchy.

Comment: But we do get the same problem with trb_output: try `trb_output %>%   slice(5) %>%  pull(.dat)`. I don't think we can do something here, it's due to `pull`

Comment: Oh you're right. I totally missed this... Yes the output is correct.